# Get json in request body with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get json from body of request.

This code is working :

```
public ActionResult SaveConfiguration()
{
    var input = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

}
```

But if I add a binding (from uri) in my action, that not works anymore...

```
public ActionResult SaveConfiguration(int id)
{
    var input = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

}
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC (not ASP.NET Core)

Comment: can you show the binding please? both of your snippets are the same

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Not the same (parameter id)

Comment: Should've been clearer - can you show the *routings* please above the actions?

Comment: This is defauts routings

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution (reset position on stream) :

```
public ActionResult SaveConfiguration(int id)
        {
            Request.InputStream.Position = 0;  // <= Solution
            var input = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```